# How to eliminate the so-called "ghost" pixels from the masks generated by mog algorithm?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction, mog

when i run mog algorithm using visual studio, and processing image sequences and videos as well as streaming videos from camera some of the generated masks have ghost pixels that appear in all frames. I have tried to change the parameters of the algorithm but still have the same problem. please refer to the photo bellow which illustrate what i mean. you can see that the white care in the first frame appear in the generated mask of current frame which it so far in sequence from the first frame.

how can i eliminate that?

[image: 4 photos to describe what I mean]

Comment: Can you show a few images with your _ghost_ pixels?

Comment: Try eroding the image to remove the small white blobs, then perform a few iterations of dilations to enhance the vehicle contours

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that if you have a sample code 
because i am just a beginner  . thanks

Comment: i have tried to sue this code but i think morphological operation dont solve it 
is the problem related to the learning rate?


void morphOps(Mat &thresh){

 
 Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(2,2)); 
 Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size(2,2)); 
 erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);
 erode(thresh,thresh,erodeElement);

 dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);
 dilate(thresh,thresh,dilateElement);
}`